# Post attachment and additional form fields using Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to create a form that allows the user to specify subject, body, attachment and post to an action using the web api and jquery. im not sure how to approach this.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use use Json to hold the subject and body and then use the formdata to send the file. You can use $.ajax function to send the data data to server. You can then just parse the Json in the server code.